# notepad++ themes - Converted clouds midnight textmate theme, not the same

Tags: styles, themes, notepad++, textmate

I have converted the Clouds Midnight theme to use it in notepad++, however it still does not seem to be the same. I have downloaded the monaco font, however even this font is not the same as you see here.

http://fredhq.com/projects/clouds

I have put the converted theme into the C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes directory,

Thoughts? It must be something simple that im missing! Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not seem to be the same"? Do you have a screenshot of how it looks in Notepad++? Please bear in mind that Windows and OS X render fonts vastly differently even if you use the same font.

Comment: 1. How did you convert the theme? 2. Why do you want to use Monaco instead of Consolas? And +1 to Boltclock, even if he pretends to be a unicorn.

Comment: +1 to BoltClock, post a screenshot of how it looks different. Also, did you try pasting your theme to your `%AppData% path: "C:\Users\[User_name]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++". If you used the default install options for Notepad++, customized themes and styles have to be placed here

Answer (score 0):

The font used is Inconsolata-dz, downloadable (for free) here: http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/